# How to place two buttons on top of tableview

Tags: iphone

i have been looking, but can't find my answer.
my question is how to make a tableview with two buttons above it. 
here is a pic of something i would like to do.

I have the grouped tableview, but can't figure out how to make it look like the image.

thanks for the help

http://img137.imageshack.us/i/imagezjb.png/

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with your two buttons as subviews, then set the [`tableHeaderView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) property on your table view to be that view.

Answer (score 0):

@LucasTizma's answer is valid but you can also return views for header sections by implementing the method below, which returns a UIView. In this case, you will be able to return different views for different header sections so if for instance you had a header for Games and a header for Utilities on the same tableView, you could return different images/buttons for each header (i.e. a special game promo in the game section and a different one for Utilities).

Basically the process is the same: you create a UIView, add the buttons/images as subviews and then return it on the method.

`- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

Cheers,
Rog